# Scrollbars don't take on framework styling until interacted with

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I'm using `Modern Metro UI framework` installed from `Nuget`in a `Win Forms` application and the scrollbars don't take on the styling until interacted with. That includes resizing the application window.

Scroll bar on initial load, not styled:

[image: scrollbar not styled]

Style taking affect after using scroll bar:
[image: scrollbar styled]

Any ideas on why this is happening? The scrollbars are not programmatically added. I'm using the `metro grid`which I believe is the `data grid view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the data grid and using a new one.